# Simplify a square root by factoring it for sum-product method

Tags: radicals

I ran into a mathematical problem which I guess I can simplify by *product-sum* factoring, I learned this approach while studying in Kumon, but I am afraid I have forgotten.

This is the expression:

$\sqrt{10 - 2 \sqrt{ 21 } }.$

Notice that $7\cdot 3$ equal to $21$ and $7+3$ equal to $10$, thus we can factor this by the sum-product method.

How can I tackle this problem by using this algorithm?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$10-2\sqrt{21}=(\sqrt7)^2-2\sqrt7\sqrt3+(\sqrt3)^2.$$

Comment: Yves Daoust, Could you please explain the algorithm you used in order to simplify the expression?

Comment: @MatheusMinguini: remarkable identity.